# DataFrame, count unique values, Java

Tags: java-8, apache-spark-sql

I have a [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) and I want to count the uniqe lines of two columns in this Data Frame. For example:

```
a x
a x
a y
b y 
b y
b y
```

should be to:

```
a x 2
a y 1
b y 3
```

I know the solution for this operation in pandas DataFrame, but now I want to do it direct in Java (the best way is Java 8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the next solution by myself. Copy here, if somebody has an interest....

```
DataFrame df2 = df.groupBy("Column_one", "Column_two").count();
df2.show();
```

Comment: Where’s the relationship to Java 8?

Comment: If you have the shorter solution in Java 8, you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what input type you have, but assuming you have a `List<DataFrame> list` and `DataFrame` implements equals/hashcode as expected, you could use a combination of two collectors:

```
Map<DataFrame, Long> count = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(x -> x, counting()));
```

which requires the following static imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

Comment: I have input type DataFrame and the type of the columns is String.